# How to use pytorch to construct multi-task DNN, e.g., for more than 100 tasks?

Tags: deep-learning, regression, classification, pytorch

Below is the example code to use pytorch to construct DNN for two regression tasks. The `forward` function returns two outputs (x1, x2). How about the network for lots of regression/classification tasks? e.g., 100 or 1000 outputs. It definitely not a good idea to hardcode all the outputs (e.g., x1, x2, ..., x100). Is there an simple method to do that? Thank you.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class mynet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mynet, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(5, 10)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(10, 3)
        self.lin3 = nn.Linear(10, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x1 = self.lin2(x)
        x2 = self.lin3(x)
        return x1, x2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = torch.randn(1000, 5)
    y1 = torch.randn(1000, 3)
    y2 = torch.randn(1000,  4)
    model = mynet()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=1e-4)
    for epoch in range(100):
        model.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out1, out2 = model(x)
        loss = 0.2 * F.mse_loss(out1, y1) + 0.8 * F.mse_loss(out2, y2)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58097924/1714410),

Answer (score 5):

You can (and should) use [`nn` containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers) such as [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#modulelist) or [`nn.ModuleDict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#moduledict) to manage arbitrary number of sub-modules.

For example (using [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#modulelist)):

```py
class MultiHeadNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, list_with_number_of_outputs_of_each_head):
        super(MultiHeadNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.backbone = ...  # build the basic "backbone" on top of which all other heads come
        # all other "heads"
        self.heads = nn.ModuleList([])
        for nout in list_with_number_of_outputs_of_each_head:
            self.heads.append(nn.Sequential(
              nn.Linear(10, nout * 2),
              nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
              nn.Linear(nout * 2, nout)))

    def forward(self, x):
        common_features = self.backbone(x)  # compute the shared features
        outputs = []
        for head in self.heads:
            outputs.append(head(common_features))
        return outputs
```

Note that in this example each head is more complex than a single `nn.Linear` layer.
The number of different "heads" (and number of outputs) is determined by the length of the argument `list_with_number_of_outputs_of_each_head`.

---

**Important notice:** it is crucial to use [`nn` containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers), rather than simple pythonic lists/dictionary to store all sub modules. Otherwise pytorch will have difficulty managing all sub modules.
See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279872/1714410), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54678896/1714410) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57320958/1714410).