# torch.nn.DataParallel and to(device) does not support nested modules

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a torch.nn.module class defined in the following way:

```
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
       super(MyModule, self).__init__()
       self.sub_module_a = ....  # nn.module
       self.sub_module_b_dict = {
          'B': .... # nn.module
       }
```

However after I call `torch.nn.DataParallel(MyModule)` and `MyModule.to(device)` only `sub_module_a` is put on cuda. The 'B' inside `self.sub_module_b_dict` is still on CPU.

Looks like DataParallel and to(device) only support first level variables inside a torch.nn.Module class. The modules nested inside a customized structure (in this case, a dictionary) seem to be ignored.

Am I missing some caveats here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **MUST** use proper [`nn` containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers) for all `nn.Module`'s methods to act recursively on sub modules.

In your case, `'B'` module is stored in a simple pythonic dictionary. Replace this with [`nn.ModuleDict`] and you should be fine:

```py
self.sub_module_b_dict = nn.ModuleDict({'B': ...})
```

See related threads:
[a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372348/1714410), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684415/1714410), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279872/1714410), [d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764387/1714410), [e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58098215/1714410), to name just a few...